# if we execute a update statement and a delete statement parallel in sql server 2008 having isolation level at Read committed. What will be the output

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

if a transaction is having multiple select statements feteching data from a table and parallel to it another query runs that is deleting the set of records fetched in the previoius transaction. What will be the result of select statement within the transaction that executes after the delete query.

isolation level is set to Read committed.

```
Begin Trans A

select * from myTable where id >100 and id <1000

//while loop //some time taking operation. Here parallel the delete query executes 

select * from myTable where id >100 and id <1000 //**what would be the output of this query ?**

commit trans A

--------

//some other delete query delete from myTable where id > 500 and id <1000
```

Comment: Why not mock up a test with a dummy database? You seem to know what you want to test.

Answer (score 0):

Since RCI only holds the locks for the duration of the statement then it's all going to depend on timing. Assuming the order you have and that the delete also happens in RCI and in its own transaction the first select will bring back all of the data, the delete starts and the other select starts. Their could be a deadlock (depending) but most likely one of the statements is going to get its locks granted first and the other will wait until it can acquire the locks. It's a timing problem at this point.

If you run these in a tight enough loop you'll hit some interesting results. If you wanted a more stable return value set then use snapshot isolation.